# Location-scale family

Tags: statistics

I am really struggling with the definition of a location-scale family. I have an intuition about it, but I cannot answer the questions about it.
I want to show that the exponential distribution belongs to the location-scale family associated with the standard exponential distribution $x\mapsto 1-e^{-x}$. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Exponential distribution **does not** belong to  a location - scale family. Actually it belongs to a *"scale family"*

***Definition***

A scale family of distributions has densities of the form

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{
g(x|\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta}\cdot\psi\left(\frac{x}{\theta}  \right)
\qquad (1) 
}
$$

where $\theta>0$ and $\psi$ is a density.

Now let's take the pdf of an exponential rv.

$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\theta}e^{-x/\theta}$$

It is immediate to recognize that $f_X(x)$ is in the form (1) where $\psi=e^{-y}$ is the density of a negative exponential rv with mean 1

Note that $\theta$ in this density is called "Scale parameter" exactly for this reason.

---

as a further example,

1. $X\sim N(\mu;\sigma^2)$ belongs to a *location - scale* family.
2. $X\sim N(\mu;\mu^2)$ belongs to a *scale* family.
3. $X\sim N(1;\theta)$ **does not** belong to a *scale* family.

Try to prove it using the corresponding definitions